# iFrame Auto Height

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is there a way to do this with iFrame and have it working with all browsers? Or would I have to go about using Javascript. If either, can someone help me?

I need to have an auto height so it expands as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20789453/1435655

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for me some time ago. It's without JS, but you have to use the `table`. This is how I used it for me, maybe you will need little changes for your needs.

```
<head>
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0}
html, body {height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden}
table {height:100%;width:100%;table-layout:static;border-collapse:collapse}
iframe {height:100%;width:100%}

.header {border-bottom:1px solid #000}
.content {height:100%}
</style>
</head>

<table>
  <td class="header"></td>
  <td class="content" width="80%" valign="top"><iframe id="reportframe" src="src.html" frameborder="0"></td>
</table>
```